# Ordering and filtering data from csv.dictreader

Tags: python, python-3.x, csv, sorting, dictionary

```
import csv

with open ('data_airbnb.csv', newline='') as f:
    reader = csv.DictReader(f, delimiter = ',')
    data_list = list(reader)
```

The below is 1 sample data_list content:

```
[OrderedDict([('room_id', '3179080'), ('survey_id', '1280'), ('host_id', '15295886'), ('room_type', 'Shared room'), ('country', ''), ('city', 'Singapore'), ('borough', ''), ('neighborhood', 'TS17'), ('reviews', '15'), ('overall_satisfaction', '5.0'), ('accommodates', '12'), ('bedrooms', '1.0'), ('bathrooms', ''), ('price', '77.0'), ('minstay', ''), ('last_modified', '2017-05-17 09:10:24.216548'), ('latitude', '1.310862'), ('longitude', '103.858828'), ('location', '0101000020E6100000E738B709F7F659403F1BB96E4AF9F43F')])
```

Dear friends, Im trying to retrieve the **top 10 priciest room (price) with room_id** and put them **into a list** from the data_list which contains thousands of rows. the sample list I shown was 1 row of it?

I have tried it before for a simple list but I have been receiving error accessing the values for this and do not know how to do it.

please advice. Thanks

Comment: you're right. So now why using `next` ? it's used to skip title lines, but if you use it in csv dict readers you just lose one line of data.

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre, Good point, possibly there's an empty / unused line in the csv file. Given the output OP is getting it *seems* they are reading correctly.

Answer (score 2):

One way is to sort your list of dictionaries and select the first 10 elements. You can achieve this via `sorted` and a custom function:

```
res = sorted(data_list, key=lambda x: float(x['price']), reverse=True)[:10]
```

**Explanation**

- `lambda` represents an anonymous function; you could alternatively use an explicit named function with the same logic.
- `float` conversion is necessary to avoid comparing strings, which are currently used to represent prices in your `OrderedDict` objects.
- `reverse=True` ensures we are ordering by highest price first.
- Since `sorted` returns a list, you can use regular list slicing via `[:10]` to extract the first 10 elements.

Comment: I like the `heapq` method better, though.

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre, Yep, you're right it's much more efficient. Hopefully someone will post that; it should be the recommended practice for such problems.

Comment: Im supposed to read the data in the dict and get the top 10 price and room_id. How do I go about linking it?

Comment: `How do I go about linking it?` Sorry, I don't understand which bit in the solution above isn't clear. `data_list` is exactly as in your question.

Comment: Im trying to retrieve the price with room_id from the data_list which contains thousands of rows. the sample list I shown was 1 row of it

Answer (score 1):

Reusing the proper key function from [jpp answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51648993/6451573), you can directly get the 10 top values by using `heapq` module (saves list slicing, the reverse flag, but the internals are the same, Python has to completely sort the list before deciding which 10 top values to keep):

```
import heapq
top10 = heapq.nlargest(10,data_list,key=lambda x: float(x['price']))
```

Aside, I see that you have a `next(reader)` statement, which is generally used in csv readers to skip the title line, but here your title line is already consumed by the dictionary reader, so maybe it's a mistake that drops one line of data, and potentially useful information. With that bug fixed, the shortest code I could propose would be:

```
import heapq,csv
with open ('data_airbnb.csv', newline='') as f:
    top10 = heapq.nlargest(10,csv.DictReader(f),key=lambda x: float(x['price']))
```

- you don't have to force conversion to `list`, it is done by `heapq` internally when data isn't a list (performance could paradoxally be worse, though)
- `,` is the default csv separator, no need to specify it